# MySQL taking high CPU Usage

Tags: mysql

I have dedicated linux server with 4 cores and 8GB RAM. I have one webportal developed in crash php and mysql. On single page it pushing near about 15-20 queries. On each page I have included mysql connection. My Problem is everytime mysql service taking 50% cpu while sometime 160-200%. When it reaches to 200%, my server get hang and need to restart.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST;` showing no queries pending.
I have optimized all tables using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` query. Some of tables are INNODB while some are MYISAM. I have checked slow query logs who is tracking queries greater than 1 second. There are few queries which taking time not greater than 2-3 seconds.

my.cnf file contain

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time=1
log_queries_not_using_indexes=0
log_error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log

[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_safe_error.log
```

Comment: Is there anything showing in the slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log ?

Comment: Yes there are some queries which taking time greater than 1 second. These query's time is from 2-3 secs.

Comment: You may want to try asking questions specific about how to optimise those queries.

Comment: But these are very simple quries.. like `SELECT image FROM artist WHERE artist_id=1234` very few queries are joined.

Comment: Have you indexed artist_id ?

Comment: By the way how many records do you have in the "artist" table?